# Is there a for a useful C++ wrapper class for Windows resource load strings?

Tags: c++, windows, string, resources, wrapper

We're working on localizing our app and now have the chore of fixing all the hard coded strings to LoadString(), etc.

I have taken a quick look [at this class](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/stringtable.aspx) but wonder if anyone has used any other good wrappers.

Some requirements/nice to haves:

- terse replacements for the hardcoded strings - we don't want to add lines and lines of code.
- free and royalty-free

EDIT
A little more information - 
the hardcoded strings were all throughout the code.  Sometimes they were converted by the compiler to CString, sometimes to std::string and sometimes just plain old char*.

We want to minimize the changes to the code base (250k+ lines of code - and would rather not do much to the places where all the strings are used as different types.

Thus the class/method must do multiple duty as wchar, CString, std::string, etc...

Comment: We just made it work the same way as CMsg you refer to, it seems to work fine for now

Comment: What do you want to load the string into? ATL/WTL/MFC CString? STL std::[w]string? TCHAR array?

Comment: @Rob - Don't really care - just needs to be usable in the application.  Right now we use std::string and CString - and will likely use the CString::LoadString() unless we have a better alternative.

Comment: If you're already using CString, there's no reason not to use the LoadString() method.

Comment: @Billy - We are using CStrings in some cases, but in others they were std::strings as well as straight char *, etc.  We want to minimize the impact on the code base (hundreds of thousands of lines of code).

Answer (score 4):

I think a class is overkill for this. I use this one:

```
inline const wchar_t * LoadResourceString(UINT resourceId)
{
    wchar_t * buff;
    int requiredLen = LoadStringW(
        GetModuleHandle(0), // Replace this with your HINSTANCE if
                            // using a resource DLL of course :)
        resourceId,
        reinterpret_cast<LPWSTR>(&buff),
        0);
    if (requiredLen == 0)
    {
        THROW_LAST_WINDOWS_ERROR();
    }
    return buff;
}
```

EDIT: Of course you would need to put the `HINSTANCE` somewhere if you were intending to use this in a resource DLL. This assumes the resource strings are ecoded as part of a single binary.

Comment: @Ben: Did you read the docs for [`LoadStringW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647486.aspx)? Regarding the last parameter: "If this parameter is 0, then lpBuffer receives a read-only pointer to the resource itself."

Comment: `buff` should be a `const wchar_t*`... and a comment explaining the really weird exceptional behavior when length of 0 is passed would be good.  In pretty much every other Windows API function, passing a length of zero means, don't get the data, but tell me how long it is so I can allocate the buffer.

Comment: @Ben: I don't design the API, I just write code against it :) And `buff` cannot be `const` because the parameter to `LoadStringW` is not `const`. (I would need to const_cast in addition to the reinterpet_cast)

Comment: And I think I would use `LoadResource` / `SizeofResource` / `LockResource`, which doesn't flaunt type-safety nearly as badly and also actually tells you how long the data was.

Comment: @Billy: I didn't suggest making `wchar_t* const buff`.

Comment: @Ben: LoadStringW does return the size of the returned resource -- I just don't expose it in this function because for what I was doing I did not need it. I agree that the type safety violation here is a big one, but again, I didn't design it. That's why I hide the nasty type violations for this C API call behind the function.

Comment: @Billy: MSDN gives no information that I can find about the return code from `LoadString` when the special length == 0 case is invoked.

Comment: @Ben: Not sure if it's supposed to be documented that way, but it works for me. (Actually, the predecessor to this method used the returned length to build a `std::wstring`. I replaced it with this only because I found the only time I used methods like this was to turn around and pass them right back into Win32 (i.e. for a Window title).

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I use:

```
extern HINSTANCE GetResourceInstance(); //Define elsewhere, or use a global hInst

template<int N>
class LoadStringRes
{
    TCHAR tszString[N+1];
public:
    LoadStringRes(int ID)
    {
        ::LoadString(GetResourceInstance(), ID, tszString, sizeof(tszString)/sizeof(tszString[0]));
    }

    operator const TCHAR*() const
    {
        return tszString;
    }
};
```

Use thusly:

```
MyFunctionThatNeedsAString(LoadStringRes<100>(IDS_HELLO));
```

It looks like a function call, but it's really an object construction/use/destruction/use.

The downside is that you have to know the ballpark length of the string. That's the price of the automatic/stack memory allocation.

Comment: No need to define it statically. That's what `GetModuleHandle(NULL)` is for.

Comment: Not if resource DLLs are employed. Which is what the OP is after IMHO.

Comment: @Seva Yes, that is what we are after - resource DLLs for other languages.

Comment: @Seva: Also note that you don't need to have a buffer lying around if you use LoadStringW, because it can return a pointer to the direct location in memory where the string is stored. (That call is shown in my answer)

Comment: Good point. The OP never spelled out what's their charset policy.

Comment: RE the charset - we are migrating from 8 bits to unicode - not a pretty sight.  The codebase is 10+ years old.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [wxWidgets](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_locale.html). It *will* increase your distributable setup file, but it is very powerful and provides lots of features (in addition to the one your're seeking) in a very elegant and efficient manner (yes, it's free and royalty-free).

Comment: 2.4MB+ of binary for loading a simple resource seems like overkill to me. YMMV.

Comment: @Billy I agree but in case he desires a longer term solution, it's a great library.

Comment: wxWidgets is not suitable for us.  I am aware of it for other cross-platform stuff - but this is apparently going to be a windows only codebase.  The company will not like it as a solution - regardless of my opinions on the matter.

Comment: @Android: Yes, I agree it's nice from a developer's prospective to use. Just expensive in terms of code size.

Comment: @Android : why are you bringing in a "library" when wrapper class/function will do the job ? Imagine if every developer in a collaborative project does this....

Comment: @YeenFei  Au contraire, my friend. Imagine if every developer in a collaborative project writes her own wrapper class/function... Oh wait, this is already happening. :)